# Apache CXF timeout not working on peak traffic

Tags: java, soap, timeout, cxf

I have some trouble trying to find root cause on why soap call timeout is being ignored at times. I also can't replicate it locally.

It only happens on production server during peak hours/heavy load. Timeout is working off-peak hours.

Below is how timeout out is being setup on code

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(serviceClass);
factory.setAddress(address);

Object object = factory.create();
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(object);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(10000);
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(25000);
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Apache cxf 2.2.5 is the library being used.

Updating library might not be an option as this is an old project and updating might break or bring more problems as is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Intermittent failures can be very difficult solving first person.  More so for others.  Can you give any more failure analysis?  Just a guess, increase priority of thread monitoring timeout.

Comment: A quick google doesn't show up how to modify thread priority specifically for the timeout on the cxf library. I might be wrong but i will check docs for it. I believe the timeout implementation can't be modified unless we modify the library itself, if that is the case i'm pretty sure the project won't allow it.